# Can I give up on a den that's being attacked by Templars?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I spent too much time with my Templar Awareness meter full and now they're attacking one of my dens. It's way the heck on the other side of the city from where I am, and I'm in the middle of something. I don't feel like running back over to defend the den. What will happen if I don't? Will I lose the den and have to re-capture it from the Templars, or will they just keep attacking until I show up and defend (or fail to defend) it? Will the den-on-fire icon just stay on my map, or will it go away eventually?

I'm very early into the game and I haven't done any recruiting/assigning of assassins, or anything like that. So: what are the consequences of letting one of my dens fall to the Templars?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They'll wait for you to get there.  I'm not sure if there are any consequences if you go forever without even visiting that den, but it doesn't seem like there will be...I can confirm that they'll wait at least several hours.

If you fail a den defense, the only consequence is that the den reverts to Templar control, and you have to kill the captain all over again - it's like you never had it in the first place.

Comment: In my experience it doesn't really matter if you protect them or not. In the end I only went there if I had to go there for a quest, which ends up saving you a lot of time

Comment: @IvoFlipse I believe you lose income from owned properties in the den's radius.

Answer (score 2):

The den will remain contested until you choose to defend it. Should you fail Den Defense, you can always capture it back. However, your apprentices gain experience from successfully defending a den.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played the game personally, but I do remember seeing a quote about this very topic in the [IGN review of the game.](http://ps3.ign.com/articles/121/1212370p2.html)

> > Frequently the game throws overwhelming odds against you, making the entire affair an irritating, extraneous mess. Even more irritating - if you lose, you can immediately climb a wall and assassinate the enemy leader again, rendering your previous 10-minute chore almost pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Let the den go if you don't want to defend it. Capturing it back is so much easier than defending it.