# How much time do I have before one of my dens is recaptured?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Templars are attacking my dens a lot and I strongly dislike the Den Defense minigame, so I'm tempted to ignore the attacks.

I'm assuming my dens are going to get recaptured by the templars sooner or later, so I don't want to ignore the attacks for too long, but how long is too long? Should I always drop everything and go rescue my dens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I give up on a den that's being attacked by Templars?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38098/can-i-give-up-on-a-den-thats-being-attacked-by-templars)

Comment: @agent86 Not sure this is a complete duplicate, but I agree it's pretty close. Probably close enough. :)

Comment: Yeah, it rung a bell so I marked it, my apologies if there's enough different to keep this one open as well.

Comment: I go back to my den, start the defense mission, and let the Templars kick my ass while I go make some coffee. I come back and kill the Templar Captain again and then it's like it never happened.

Answer (score 8):

From what I have read, the dens only get recaptured if you actually fail the Den Defense mini-game, so if you never get to it, they shouldn't get recaptured.

Comment: This is correct.  Of course, the city will be swarming with templars if you do this.  Why not just max out your den leaders?

Comment: @Shinrai That's a work in progress.

Answer (score 2):

I stopped defending them and I don't think one of them got reclaimed. I ended up getting the master assassins trained up so I wouldn't have to risk failing again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of keeping your dens safe is to keep the Templar awareness level low by bribing heralds and killing officials. By doing this, I only had to do the den defense 3 or 4 times in my run through the game, though I could probably have gotten away with less if I was more careful.

I particularly recommend using poison darts for dealing with the officials, as they can be fired from a safe distance without alerting the guards. Just make sure to stay in the area while the poison takes effect.